# How to get the cartesian product?

Tags: r, dataframe, expand

I have a data frame like this:

| plazo | monto |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 2 |
| 50 | 3 |

I need to add a rows for values between 1 to the value of `plazo` and expand my dataframe like below;

| plazo | monto | Semana |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 2 | 1 |
| 20 | 2 | 2 |
| 20 | 2 | 3 |
| 20 | 2 | … |
| 20 | 2 | 20 |
| 50 | 3 | 1 |
| 50 | 3 | 2 |
| 50 | 3 | 3 |
| 50 | 3 | … |
| 50 | 3 | 50 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a nested column with values from `1:plazo` for each row and then `unnest` that column.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(plazo = c(2, 5), monto = c(2,3))

library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Semana = list(1:plazo)) %>% 
  unnest(Semana)

#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>   plazo monto Semana
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
#> 1     2     2      1
#> 2     2     2      2
#> 3     5     3      1
#> 4     5     3      2
#> 5     5     3      3
#> 6     5     3      4
#> 7     5     3      5
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   uncount(plazo, .id = 'Semana', .remove = FALSE)
```

-output

```
  plazo monto Semana
1     2     2      1
2     2     2      2
3     5     3      1
4     5     3      2
5     5     3      3
6     5     3      4
7     5     3      5
```